# Easy and efficient way to run GNU/Linux on top of Android on an x86 device?

Tags: installation, linux

I have a quite powerful x86-64 [Android phone](http://www.smartprix.com/mobiles/asus-zenfone-2-ze551ml-4gb-ram-128gb-p1101kdfou7m). I want to run a GNU/Linux desktop distro (preferably Debian-based) on top of Android.

I have the stock firmware, but rooted and with Xposed Framework.

I know about [Complete Linux Installer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.zpwebsites.linuxonandroid&hl=en), and it seems excellent. But they have a pre-prepared image. I assume that image is ARM, so it won't work? Right? Also, they say my ROM has to support "loop-devices." Does it? And if it doesn't is there any tweak to enable it?

But I'm sure there must also be tons of other ways to do it? FWIW I have access to a laptop with an Intel processor that I can use for the process. (But I'm not too keen on hours of tinkering to make it work.)

Other than that, I want to really take advantage of the specs of the phone. A user friendly process is also a plus.

Please note that even though I have a accepted my own answer here, I still very much welcome additional answers.

Comment: Complete Linux Installer crashes on my rooted Samsung S4 running CM13. Linux Deploy works though.

Comment: @Matthieu CLL also crashed on my rooted Samsung S3. Never tried LD on the Samsung.

Comment: You don't need to use any third party app to run Linux on Android device. Just get the rootfs of any distro you want to run, mount it and `chroot` into it from any terminal emulator app like Termux. Very minimal configuration is needed usually e.g. adding new user, adding DNS server etc. I use Ubuntu, ArchLinuxARM and VoidLinux this ways on my device. In addition to `chroot` I also use mount, PID, network and UTS namespaces to further isolate Linux environment from Android. Also possible to use VNC or XServer, but I don't do usually.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found  way to do this that I'm very happy with.

I used [Linux Deploy](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ru.meefik.linuxdeploy&hl=en). (It requires root, but here's [an alternative](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.cuntubuntu&hl=en) for those who don't want to root.)

Here's a *nearly full* version of Xubuntu 16.04 (x86-64) running on my phone.

[image]

It performs really well. I had no performance issues. Note that this is *not* a virtual machine. Android and Xubuntu share the very same Linux kernel at the same time. If, while this is running, I switch to [OS monitor](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.eolwral.osmonitor&hl=en) (in Android), I can actually see the individual processes from Xubuntu (`dpkg`, etc.) running and how much of the CPU they're using. (That has to be enabled in a setting, though.)

An external keyboard and mouse are a must (though not strictly required). And an external monitor is also a good idea. Or you can just VNC into this system directly from another computer. Linux Deploy supports that out of the box.

The setup is really easy. The default settings of Linux Deploy pretty much work. Just select your distribution and desktop environment. But, by default, the system creates a 2GB `.img` file as a file system. That wasn't enough for me. So since the internal storage of my phone is `ext4` formatted, I was able to set it to 40 GB. If yours is FAT32, the maximum will be 4GB. But it's also possible to have a directory or partition instead of a `.img` file. (Although I didn't figure out how to do that.)

The process is [described in detail here](http://www.linux-magazine.com/Online/Features/Convert-an-Android-Device-to-Linux). Skip down to the "Linux Deploy" section. It's important that you install the correct version of Busy Box. Otherwise, it won't work.

This kind of thing has potential. If you have a powerful enough phone, it can actually replace your desktop computer in many cases.

Comment: You mentionned *an external keyboard and mouse are a must*. You mean you could install one actually *on* your phone? I'd be interested to do that, as my rooted Samsung S4 microphone is dead, but the phone is powerful.

Comment: You might also want to accept your own answer. I think it makes sense, seeing VirtualBox running on Android! :)

Comment: @Matthieu Sure, keyboard and mouse are possible on the S4. Just get an USB-OTG cable and a hub. Even better, get an OTG that supports charging at the same time (rare.) Connect to an external screen, and your phone has become a real desktop computer. Personally, I use Bluetooth for the keyboard and mouse. Regarding Virtual Box, while I managed to install it, I [still haven't been able](http://askubuntu.com/q/792896/451919) to actually get it to work (that would be _so_ cool, though.) I think on your Samsung you have to ARM compile a lot of packages from source? Can the S4 manage it, you think?

Comment: I'm not sure. One of the reason I wanted to have a full Linux was getting gcc to compile native stuff, but I couldn't find it so far (I didn't try very hard either). Virtual Box on ARM probably needs a lot of those. Thanks for the USB-OTG, it sounds nice!

Comment: @Matthieu VirtualBox would never even be possible to install on ARM. It's purely for x86. (My phone is x86.) But for most other FOSS software, you might be able to ARM compile from source. Some stuff is also available through `apt-get`. But it's definitely easier with x86. And yeah, OTG is pretty cool. You can even connect storage devices, and (with a powered hub) HDDs. And with root you can get Android drivers for NTFS and HFS+. It becomes more and more like a real desktop computer.

Comment: I tried the Ubuntu and its `apt-get` but it failed for the gcc packages, probably because of the libc not being so standard. Without a compiler it will be difficult to get anything to work (beyond what's already working of course). Though Terminal IDE sounds like a nice project regarding compiling on Android...

Comment: @Matthieu Isn't there any other way to get a compiler?

Comment: I think Terminal IDE is the best (free) bet.

Comment: @Matthieu I'm sure you'll figure it out.

Comment: @beeshyams I feel that accepting my own answer discourages further answers. And I want to encourage more answers. There are multiple ways of doing this. I feel that accepting my own answer doesn't really serve any purpose.

Comment: Intention is noble , a) but you are forgetting that you can accept a better answer at a later point of time b) This being a niche problem, it signifies that a working solution exists for those niche seekers- Your choice of course

Comment: @beeshyams Alright, I've accepted. Can always change it later if something better comes along.

Comment: You may even add a note to your question saying that while you have one solution- would welcome better solutions- this may encourage

Comment: @beeshyams Good idea.